# Is there a way to change the url path of a PDF manually and have it update real time?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm building an app for my school which includes a lunch menu, however since the lunch menu changes every month I don't want to keep updating my app just for that. I know you can open PDFs with Xcode either locally or online, but is there a way to change the url path of the pdf manually and have it update real time within the app. Any help would be much appreciated and I'm new to developing IOS apps, so any links that may help would be great.

Comment: I assume that the PDF is published online so I imagine you could add a variable in the path, with the week. For exemple: http://example.com/201615/lunch.pdf :  the lunch menu for the week 15 of 2016. Your app will just have to calculate the week, and the document will be different each week

Answer (score 0):

If you control the website or have a line of communication with the person who does then you could agree that the latest menu always gets returned from `example.com/current/lunch.pdf` but really this should be set up as a GET request `example.com/index.php?lunchmenu=current` so that it is down to the website to respond with the file or the file location rather than the app's responsibility to guess the filename. So for example:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/index.php?lunchmenu=current") {

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(d,_,_) in
        if let data = d {
         String(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) // this is could be your file name
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

It would then be possible to perform other requests like: `example.com/index.php?lunchmenu=nextmonth`. Working in this way means that if for some reason the naming pattern or location of the files changed your app would still keep working.

If you don't have access to the school website but do know where the file is stored, you could query your own website for the file information and either update this automatically (or if there was no other way - manually). Again, this would prevent an app update if the structure of the school website changed.

Only rely on static file locations and naming systems if you really have to.

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks you so much for your time and help. Trying to learn step by step as i only have been coding for like 3 months and hopefully to continue to be better at this.